# react-native type check on component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, typechecking

I have a component that I want to be able to handle two kinds of components. One is a Text component, the other Image component.

I have some default styles like the color I want to be able to apply that to both components, however, a text element can use the key of color in its styles, but on an Image, it has to be tintColor key.

Is there any way I can check for which element I have so I can set the appropriate styles to each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can use 3 styles object to handle it like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  default: { marginTop: 10, borderWidth: 1 },
  onlyButton: { borderColor: '#F0F' },
  onlyText: { borderColor: '#C9F' },
})

<Text style={[styles.default, styles.onlyText]} />
<TouchableOpacity={[styles.default, styles.onlyButton]} />
```

Note that the code above might have typos, it's just an example to show the idea.

Let me know if it helped, or if I misunderstood your question.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can find many components have such behavior, including some official ones.

e.g: `<ScrollView />` with `style`, `contentContainerStyle`, `indicatorStyle`.

For your component, it could be:

```js
<CompositeComponent
  style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}
  textStyle={{color: 'black'}}
  imageStyle={{tintColor: 'black'}}
  />
```

and in your `render()` function,

```js
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={{[this.props.style, this.props.textStyle]}} />
      <Image style={{[this.props.style, this.props.imageStyle]}} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

This way `<Text />` and `<Image />` share the same `style`, and then overwritten each with `textStyle` or `imageStyle`.